# Keep updating data

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth

I am doing a project which receive the data from bluetooth. I want to show the data in every second via using NSLog. However, the data is just keep showing the initial value. For example the data are 0,7,4,9,1,5,2 etc and these data save in a variable(such as variableData), but now the NSLog is keep showing 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: You should post some code if you want to be answered...

Comment: Explain - how does NSLog you've mentioned is connected to variableData, does this data really changes, etc